# mongodb aggregate - select with special conditions

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have 2 collections.
1. user:

```
{
    "_id": "111",
    ...,
    "type": 1
}
```

2. query:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58bbf5bf17cc9100046b0dff"
    },
    "query": "some query",
    "user_id": "111",
    "links": []
}
```

What i want to select: **all queries for some special user type**. 
Now I'm selecting all users with some user type and include all it's queries as a field - that's not actually what I need.

```
db.collection('user').aggregate([
        {$match : {'type': userType}},
        {$lookup: {from: 'query', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user_id', as: 'queries'}},
        {$unwind: '$queries'}
    ], function(err, results) {...});
```

Thanks.

**Edit:**
Example: I want to select all the queries for the users with the `type` `1`. So expect output is like:

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58bbf5bf17cc9100046b0dff"
    },
    "query": "some query",
    "user_id": "111",
    "links": []
},
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58bbf5bf17cc9100046b0dff"
    },
    "query": "some query",
    "user_id": "111",
    "links": []
}]
```

Comment: Is `special` a user type ? I didnt understand what you mean by _all queries for some special user type_. Can you give an example and expected json output ?

Comment: @Veeram sure, i've edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would be easier to achieve this with 2 distinct queries :

1. get a list of user `_id` which have desired type
2. get all queries where userId is in the list

here is a sample script:

```
// filter users, and push all matching _id in listId field
var cursor = db.user.aggregate([{$match: {type: 1}}, {$group: {_id: null, listId: {$push: "$_id"}}}]);

if (cursor != null && cursor.hasNext()) {
   var listId = cursor.next().listId;

   // find queries where user_id is in listId
   var result = db.query.find({user_id: {$in: listId}});
   if (result != null && result.hasNext()) {
     while (result.hasNext()) {
       print(JSON.stringify(result.next())); 
    }
  }
}
```

to run it, paste the code in a file named `script.js`, and then run from your shell

```
mongo databaseName < script.js
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try below aggregation.

```
db.collection('user').aggregate([
        {$match : {'type': userType}},
        {$lookup: {from: 'query', localField: '_id', foreignField: 'user_id', as: 'queries'}},
        {$unwind: '$queries'},
        {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$queries"}}
    ]
```

Comment: nice answer but my mongo version is lower than required `3.4`